# Is there a vectorization method to match a df column to a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, vectorization

I have the following (abbreviated) dictionary:

```
_d = {
    "pain": 
        ["C0030193",
        "C0150055",
        "C0151825",
        "C0184567"],
    "anxiety": 
        ["C0003467",
        "C0003469",
        "C0027769",
        "C0154587",
        "C0231397",
        "C0231401",
        "C0231402"],
    "depression": 
        ["C0001539",
        "C0005587",
        "C0011579",
        "C0011581",
        "C0024517",
        "C0086132"],
    "fatigue": 
        ["C0015672"]
}
```

and the following dataframe:

```
df = 
    cui
1   "C0015672"
2   "C0015634"
3   "C0011579"
4   "C0030193"
5   "C0031193"
6   "C0030193"
```

I want to match up the column df["cui"], such that if the value of df["cui"] is in any of the value lists in then dictionary then I want a new column "symptom" based on the dictionary key, otherwise it would remain null.

This is the desired output:

```
df = 
        cui           symptom
    1   C0015672      fatigue 
    2   C0015634      NaN
    3   C0011579      depression 
    4   C0030193      pain
    5   C0031193      NaN
    6   C0030193      pain
```

I can do this by iterating over each row in the dataframe, but since there are 10s of millions of rows, it's super slow. I'm looking for a way to vectorize this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the dictionary first, then map the dictionary to `cui` column

```py
d = {v: k
    for k, lst in _d.items()
    for v in lst}

df['symptom'] = df['cui'].map(d)
```

Comment: Sweet! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

In case there can be multiple values per key, an option is to create a dictionary with empty lists, and append the new values to each key:

```
d = {k:[] for k in {j for i in _d.values() for j in i}}
for k1,v1 in _d.items():
    for v2 in v1:
        d.get(v2).append(k1)
df['cui'].map(d).str[0]
```